# Installed Ubuntu 17.04 from usb, but now cannot boot

Tags: grub2, uefi, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 from a live usb onto my formatted HDD, as I had done this in the past I expected it to go as it usually had. However, upon reboot I got the error that was: "Checking media presence...... No media present...... Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\shimx.efi - Not Found  Failed to load image *same path as before*: Not Found  Failed to start MokManager - Not Found"

I do have UEFI-mode enabled and my HDD is formatted with GPT.

I have attempted to use boot repair multiple times, and it says that GRUB exists on my system (and ubuntu installer states that Ubuntu 17.04 is installed also), but whenever I reboot neither GRUB or Ubuntu loads (nothing boots unless I have the live usb inserted).

Any help appreciated.

Edit:

I already had secure boot disabled.

Result of boot-repair report:
pastebin.com/xP92a5wD

Hardware specs: 
Toshiba satellite C55 B5200, 
6GB memory, 
64-bit i3

Comment: Start by disabling Secure Boot. Meanwhile [edit] the question and add the hardware specifications, make/model. If possible, run Boot Repair again, do NOT apply any fix but generate a report, post the link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same computer, except with 4GB RAM. I had the same issue with EFI booting. I would get no bootable device found.

My system had a system recovery partition first on the drive and the EFI partition second. The fix for me was to use my windows recovery disk to partition the drive. Then, delete all partitions except the first (the recovery). Then installing ubuntu.
My system also only booted by device (no OS boot) so, the default media path had to be created. Copy /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi to /EFI/BOOT/ and rename it BOOTx64.efi, worked perfectly.

Try creating an NTFS partition at the beginning of the drive and flag it as system recovery. And a FAT32 partition flagged as ESP. then installing ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

With one caveat, the error message you report seems to come from Shim (`shimx64.efi`), which implies that the computer is starting the boot process. The caveat is this: You reported the following error message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\shimx.efi - Not Found
```

This message takes the form of messages from Shim; however, Shim launches *GRUB,* and so should be complaining that it can't find `grubx64.efi`, not `shimx64.efi`. You also say it complained that it could not find MokManager, which further clarifies that this must be a Shim message -- AFAIK, no EFI looks for MokManager, but Shim does. As this is a Shim message, I'll assume you've misreported this detail. If not, then you've run into something new and weird, which could complicate my below analysis -- but maybe it still applies even then....

Your Boot Repair output indicates that `shimx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi` are both present in `EFI/ubuntu` on the ESP. Your `EFI/BOOT` directory has a `bootx64.efi` file, but it's unclear what that is from the Boot Repair output alone. As the error message references `EFI/BOOT`, though, it seems likely that `EFI/BOOT` is a copy of Shim, and that it's this binary that's running. If so, and if nothing else exists in that directory, then the error message makes sense, at least if it actually refers to `grubx64.efi`.

Given all this, the likely easiest solution is to copy `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` and `EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` to `EFI/BOOT` on the ESP (`/dev/sda1` in your case). With those files copied, Shim should be able to launch GRUB, albeit from `EFI/BOOT` rather than from `EFI/ubuntu`. This should be a fairly simple fix. This has the drawback that future updates to GRUB and Shim won't fully install -- or to be more precise, they'll be installed but will never run.

Another possible repair is suggested by the following from your Boot Repair output:

```
=================== efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0001,0003
Boot0000* ubuntu    VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0001* UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(f8a96315c2b0,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0,0)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(f8a96315c2b0,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot0003* UEFI:  USB Flash Memory1.00   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)..BO
```

This output takes some expertise to parse, but the `ubuntu` line is weird. It should normally look more like this:

```
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,6e49fcaf-d054-47c9-ba69-a668c5ee8192,0xc00,0x114000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

The details, and particularly all the hexadecimal numbers, might vary, but it would normally be an `HD(...)` entry that refers to `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. Thus, you can try this:

1. Boot an emergency disk.
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Type `sudo efibootmgr -c -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi -L ubuntu`.
4. Type `sudo efibootmgr -v` to examine the new boot order list. You should see something like the entry I showed above, and it should be first on the `BootOrder` line.

That said, both the Ubuntu installer and Boot Repair do basically this behind the scenes, and your system still has this problem. Thus, it could be that you're looking at a bug, either in your computer's firmware or in something in Ubuntu (likely `efibootmgr`, but perhaps the kernel or something else). Some Toshibas are known to have flaky EFIs, so a bug in your firmware is entirely possible. (Updating to the latest firmware, if you're not already running it, might be worth trying.)

Yet another approach is to use `fallback.efi` (aka `fbx64.efi`), which you install in `EFI/BOOT`, along with a file called `BOOT.CSV` in the `EFI/ubuntu` directory. This is a bit tedious to set up, though. See [this page of the rEFInd documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html#fallback) for details of how to do it with rEFInd -- but you'd need to tweak the details a bit to get it to work with Ubuntu. I don't see any sign of `fallback.efi` or `fbx64.efi` in your Boot Repair output, so it might not be installed on your system.

Comment: **Update:**    I re-partitioned the HDD and moved the files and changed boot order, and it took one last look at the GRUB settings in boot-repair. I can now access GRUB and Ubuntu on my HDD, it still displays the small and fast "media not found" error message before GRUB comes up, but as long as it boots I can put up with it.